# Wordpress shows death white screen on multisite

Tags: multisite, blog-page, fatal-error

I've switched from single site to multi-site and everything is running smoothly while pages are not working on sub-sites. I've created some [test pages](http://hillcountrycontemporary.com/karmacompany/testing/) on sub-sites but when I try to access them it shows white screen of death? 
The front-end pages are working fine on super site but not on sub-sites.

Also `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and `WP_DEBUG` are set to `true` but still no error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and report back. We _may_ be able to help you, but it's also likely this question will be marked off-topic for being too localized/3rd party plugin. Let's see what you get first.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic `WP_DEBUG` is set to `true` but still it does not display any error nor it logs to a `file` neither `error_log` contains anything.

Comment: Have you tried `WP_DEBUG_LOG` as `true` as well as `WP_DEBUG`? Log file is in `wp-content/debug.log`. You might need to check the logs generated by apache/your server software (some environments might prevent WordPress from overriding error reporting settings)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Both are set to `true` and I've doubled checked debug.log it does not contain anything.

Comment: Then you will need to check your server error logs - ask your host if you are unsure.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I just contacted host and the logs file doesn't have a line of `today`.

Comment: There is no way we can help you without knowing the error that is causing the WSOD.

Comment: clicking that link gave a pretty weird result for me the first time (flickering header image, garbage file not found errors)... as it redirected here: http://hillcountrycontemporary.com/?pagerd_bu4sj5254rcmxz05asjor ... then a 404 next time I tried it. quite bizarre... maybe disable/clear any caches and resave your permalink settings?

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file set up properly? Double-check it against the appropriate sample from the [htaccess Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess).

Answer (score -2):

Try to set the `WP_DEBUG` constant to `true` in `wp-config.php` file to get any errors shown in your browser.

Also, you may want to check the network has been setup correctly - double check you have followed the steps here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network